# MFC - Deactivating all buttons except one

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

I have a legacy C++ MFC application with a complex GUI with Ribbons. I have a use case as follows : User clicks button A on a ribbon panel and does some work. After his work is done, before he can exercise the rest of the GUI controls, he absolutely must click button B on the same ribbon panel, and failing to click button B in this manner results in a crash if the user exercises some other controls.

Hence, in order to deal with this use case, I figured it would solve my problem if I could disable all of program's GUI controls in Button A's event handler except button B. Button B's event handler then enables the rest of the GUI controls. This way, I ensure that button B always gets pressed after button A.

Hence, my question to you is as follows : Is there a way to disable all GUI controls in one fell swoop, and then enable and disable controls individually?

I know how to enable or disable controls individually, but I have not yet come across an API that allows one to disable all controls.

Comment: _failing to click button B in this manner results in a crash_ - Wouldn't it be better to address what's causing the crash instead of ignoring it?

Comment: What if the user invokes the same command through a menu item, or through a shortcut? Use `OnCmdUI` to disable _every_ command that's not appropriate; it'll disable the ribbon buttons as well. Note: "appropriate"; you should still fix the "crash".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way, you get all IDs of the ribbon buttons:

```
CList<UINT, UINT>& lstItems;
CMFCRibbonBar *pRibbon = ((CMDIFrameWndEx*) AfxGetMainWnd())->GetRibbonBar();
pRibbon->GetItemIDsList(lstItems);
```

Put the three lines in your view's `OnInitialUpdate()` handler.

Then use the list to compare the IDs coming through your `OnCmdMsg()` handler to disable all the buttons (except button B).